# Cucumber Rake Task resetting environment variables

Tags: ruby, cucumber, capybara, rake, rakefile

I have a rake task which sets environment variables

```
 task circle_ci_parallel_tests: :environment do
    ENV['PREPARE_TEST_DATA'] = 'true'
    Rake::Task[:service_test_data_setup].execute
      browser_group.compact.uniq.each do |browser_name|
        next unless ENV['CIRCLE_NODE_INDEX'].to_i == group_index
        ENV['BS_KEY_NAME'] = browser_name
        ENV['TEST_ENV_NUMBER'] = group_index.to_s
        ENV['BS_TYPE'] = browser_name
        run_single
      end
    end
```

I then have a rake task wrapped in a regular method

```
  def run_single
    Cucumber::Rake::Task.new(:run_features) do |task|
      output = 'tmp/failed_scenarios.txt'
      task.cucumber_opts = "features -t @leo --tags ~@no_#{ENV['BS_TYPE']} --tags ~@no_#{ENV['BS_TYPE']} -f rerun --out #{output}"
    end
    Rake::Task[:run_features].execute
  end
```

When I run the Rake::Task[circle_ci_parallel_tests] on command line
The `ENV['BS_TYPE']}` is not being set each time, but picking up the first value.

How do I make it pick up the `ENV['BS_TYPE']` each time the `run_single` method is called?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way

You need to concate the strings to the environmental variables.

```
task circle_ci_parallel_tests: :environment do
    ENV['PREPARE_TEST_DATA'] = 'true'
    ENV['BS_TYPE'] = ''
    ENV['BS_KEY_NAME'] = ''
    Rake::Task[:service_test_data_setup].execute
      browser_group.compact.uniq.each do |browser_name|
        next unless ENV['CIRCLE_NODE_INDEX'].to_i == group_index
        ENV['BS_KEY_NAME'] += ", " + browser_name.to_s
        ENV['TEST_ENV_NUMBER'] = group_index.to_s
        ENV['BS_TYPE'] += ", " + browser_name.to_s
        run_single
      end
    end
```

It will set `ENV['BS_TYPE'] and  ENV['BS_KEY_NAME']`  is something like `browser1, browser2, browser3, ...` taking all these string from `browser_group.compact.uniq` array of browsers